# How to Observe Application when user delete Manually Account?

Tags: java, android, accountmanager

I use `Account Manager` in my Android App to store user tokens and I fetch and resolve that, but I have an issue which on Android OS user can remove Account manually in Account Setting, Now how to know in the Application by real time that `Account` is removed?
is there a way to observe this in the app?

Answer (score 0):

Use `addOnAccountsUpdatedListener()` to add a listener for changes to the set of accounts.  Make sure to remove the listener appropriately or the account manager will not be garbage collected